# com.parse.ParseException: bolts.ExecutorException: An exception was thrown by an Executor

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

The similar code below is working in my app which I have developed 3-yrs back, Do I need to add and dependencies files Or is there an other way of implementing it.I have found [this](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android).

```
private void appLevel_Lang(final Context cntxt) {

    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("appSupportedLanguages");
    query.setLimit(100);
    // Get last updated date of appSupportedLanguage table from sqllite
    Date dbLastUpdatedDate = db.getLastUpdateDateOfTable("appSupportedLanguages");

    if (dbLastUpdatedDate != null) {
        query.whereGreaterThan("updatedAt", dbLastUpdatedDate);
    }
    query.orderByAscending("updatedAt");

  // run in background

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> applvl_LangList, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                if (applvl_LangList.size() > 0) {
                    String lastUpdatedDate = ParseQueries.getNSDateFormatterUpdateAtForParse().format(applvl_LangList.get(applvl_LangList.size() - 1).getUpdatedAt());

                    for (ParseObject p : applvl_LangList) {
                      // ****Insert in DB****
                        AppLevel appLevelLanguage = new AppLevel();
                        appLevelLanguage.objectID = p.getObjectId();
                        appLevelLanguage.key = p.getString("key");
                        appLevelLanguage.updatedAt = lastUpdatedDate;
                        ArrayList<String> arrLangColNames = (ArrayList<String>) ParseConfig.getCurrentConfig().get("supportedLanguages");


              // *Insert in local DB*           
          db.insertOrUpdateAppSupportedLanguageTable(appLevelLanguage);
                    }
                }

                if (applvl_LangList.size() == query.getLimit()) {
                    appLevel_Lang(cntxt);
                } else {
                    Log.d("", "AppSupportedLanguages is not equal to limit");
                }


            } else {  
              *// Show parse exception here*

                Log.d("AppSupportedLanguages", "Error: " +  e.getMessage()); 

            }
        }
    });            
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

Parse has shutdown their service on January 30, 2017

Form [Blog link](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/a-parse-shutdown-reminder/)

> we will disable the Parse service on Monday, January 30, 2017.
>   Throughout the day we will be disabling the Parse API on an app-by-app
>   basis. `When your app is disabled, you will not be able to access the`
>   `data browser or export any data, and your applications will no longer`
>   `be able to access the Parse API`.

Alternate Solutions

- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
- [Buddy](https://buddy.com/parse/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwqvvLBRDIARIsAMYuvBFOFFDgPCgHZIIl9HRROMp5Ud1NphH-NQZ16mR_GngYnrlX1C8hZLIaAn_rEALw_wcB)
- [Migration](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-parse-server-and-the-database-migration-tool/) (required your own server with node.js application support)