# ParseQuery Error inside Navigation drawer Verifier rejected class com.parse.ParseQuery

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-asynctask, verifyerror

I updated Android Studio to the last version and Graddle to 3.3 version.
Now when running the app everything goes fine, except for this error in a Parse.com Query:

> Log:
>   09-25 10:33:53.846 6313-6640/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxE/art: Verification failed on class com.parse.ParseQuery in /data/app/com.dogelier.dogelier-2/base.apk:classes30.dex because: Verifier rejected class com.parse.ParseQuery due to bad method void com.parse.ParseQuery.checkIfRunning(boolean)
>   09-25 10:33:53.846 6313-6640/com.dogelier.dogelier E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
>                                                                        Process: com.xxxxx.xxxxx, PID: 6313
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.parse.ParseQuery due to bad method void com.parse.ParseQuery.checkIfRunning(boolean) (declaration of 'com.parse.ParseQuery' appears in /data/app/com.dogelier.dogelier-2/base.apk:classes30.dex)
>                                                                            at com.dogelier.dogelier.Navegacion$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(Navegacion.java:486)
>                                                                            at com.dogelier.dogelier.Navegacion$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(Navegacion.java:462)
>                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

```
Error LINE


private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progress = new GifLoadingView();
        progress.setImageResource(R.drawable.dogelier3);
        progress.setDimming(false);
        progress.show(getFragmentManager(), "");


    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        dogelieropulationlist = new ArrayList<DogelierPopulation>();

        try {
            // ERROR LINE HERE IN PARSEQUERY
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Doghoteliers");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            //query.orderByAscending("");
            query.whereEqualTo("activado", true);
            query.setLimit(limit);


            ob = query.find();
            for (final ParseObject dogelier : ob) {
                // Locate images in flag column

             final DogelierPopulation map = new DogelierPopulation();

                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) dogelier.get("foto");
                image.getData();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeByteArray(
                                image.getData(), 0, image.getData().length);

                map.setFoto(bmp);

                map.setDireccion((String) dogelier.get("ciudad"));
                map.setNombre((String) dogelier.get("Nombre"));
                map.setTitulo((String) dogelier.get("titulo"));
                map.setDescripcion((String) dogelier.get("presentacion"));
                map.setPrecio((String) dogelier.get("precio"));
                map.setEstrellas(dogelier.getInt("Estrellas"));

                dogelieropulationlist.add(0,map);




            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error1", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorFragment = new ErrorFragment();
            manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_navegacion,
            errorFragment).commit();


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(Navegacion.this,
                dogelieropulationlist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        CloseProgress(progress);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                                new LoadMoreDataTask().execute();
                                            }
                                        }
                );
            }
        });



    }



GRADDLE

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Xxxxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxxxx'
            storeFile file('C:/KeyStores/xxxxxx.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxxxxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    } }




repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-commons-codec-1.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.2'
    compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.3'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'fr.tvbarthel.blurdialogfragment:lib:2.2.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.seatgeek:placesautocomplete:0.2-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.andremion:louvre:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.sharish:CreditCardView:v1.0.4'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'hanks.xyz:smallbang-library:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.akhgupta:android-easylocation:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.1.5'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-livequery-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.githubwing:DragPhotoView:1.0.1'
    compile 'me.shaohui.advancedluban:library:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.stepstone.apprating:app-rating:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.sandrios.android:sandriosCamera:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: You might want to read about [parse is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420209/com-parse-parseexception-bolts-executorexception-an-exception-was-thrown-by-an/45420303#45420303)

Comment: I know is gone, But I use the library for a Parse Server, specifically Sashido.

Comment: i can't guide you much in this case but error is happening due to the same reason `because: Verifier rejected class com.parse.ParseQuery due to bad method void com.parse.ParseQuery.checkIfRunning(boolean)` probably due to some configuration issues

Comment: Thnks Anyway, hope somebody help, this error is driving me crazy....:)

Comment: for future readers and for better description , you should add the details about steps , how you configured the server(sashido) with your project and related code

Comment: Please read about sahido, Is a parse.com based  server, I have several apps with them. Nothing to to with configutarion of server, since it was working fine with other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, if anyone have it in the future. Parse sdk , ParseUI and Facebook sdk my conflict if they dont point to the same version, so just make sure they are all compatible.